# How to make shared element animation from recyclerView of Fragment to viewPage of Activity with Kotin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I tried to make shared element animation from recyclerView of `Fragment` to viewPager of `Activity`.

I only can find shared element animation between fragments or activities, each.

I find that if I want to use `makeSceneTransitionAnimation`, It needs `Activity` as the first argument.

So I create interface to send items to parent fragment from adapter.

```
interface OnItemClickListener{
    fun onItemClick(v : View, data : ProductData)
}

private var listener : OnItemClickListener? = null

fun setOnItemClickListener (listener : OnItemClickListener){
    this.listener = listener
}

...

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductVH, position: Int) {
    holder.onBind(data[position],listener)
}
```

And if I click image from adapter, and send this to parent fragment.

And in parent fragment, I use `makeSceneTransitionAnimation`.

```
 val intent = Intent(this@LayoutaniActivity, SecondLayoutActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("data",data)

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){

                    val options : ActivityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                        context,v.product_img,"imageTransition"
                    )
                    context.startActivity(intent,options.toBundle())
                }
                else{
                    context.startActivity(intent)
                }
```

However it doesn't work.

I think there are two points.

It ask animation `from fragment to activity`, not `from activity to activity`.

And activity to get these animations also have viewPager.

And viewPager should also have image arrays and I want if I send position, It needs to open with animation with exact position of viewpager.

I really can't find this complicated case of shared element animation.

should I give up..? T_T

Please help me..!!